# Angular 4: Converting Http to HttpClient, config

Tags: angular, rest, angular-httpclient

I have the following code in Angular 4:

```
constructor(private baseUrl: string, private http: Http) {}

get(url: string, config?: RequestOptionsArgs): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.prependBaseUrl(url), config)
        .toPromise();
}
```

I would like to rewrite it to HttpClient instead of Http, so i modified type of http injecting to constructor, but i don't know (and can't find anywhere) what to do with `config?: RequestOptionsArgs`.

Thanks for help

Comment: so you just want to change from using in `http` to use `HttpClient` in this code above yeah?

Comment: yes, and i want to know how to pass my config there

Comment: You shouldn't have this wrapping service in the first place. Use HttpClient directly from the functional services.

Comment: wrapping httpClient methods is a bad idea, because passing dynamic config confuses linter to choose right override of `get` or other http methods

Comment: Can you show your config ? What elements it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Basic Approach:

import `HttpClientModule` and add it into app.module.ts in `imports[]`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.service.ts

import `HttpClient`  in component

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
getData(): Observable<any>{

    return this.httpClient.get('request_url',RequestOptionsArgs)
    }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {AppService} from './app.service.ts';

constructor(private appservice: AppService){
  this.appservice.getData().subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response)
})
```